# Why is Redux throwing a null error when I try to log out a user with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, redux, react-redux

To give a quick rundown of my app, it's an app where you can take tests, score yourself, and record your scores. It uses Firebase Auth and Firestore and Redux to help do all this. I'm having a problem when it comes to signing out of the user's account.

`redux/actions/index.js`:

```
import { USER_STATE_CHANGE, CLEAR_DATA, USER_TESTS_COMPLETED_STATE_CHANGE } from '../constants/index'
import firebase from 'firebase'

export function clearData() {
    return ((dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: CLEAR_DATA})
    })
}

export function fetchUser(){
    return((dispatch) => {
        firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get().then((snapshot) => {
            if(snapshot.exists){
                dispatch({type : USER_STATE_CHANGE, currentUser: snapshot.data()})
            } else {
                console.log("user data does not exist");
            }
        })
    })
}

export function fetchUserCompletedTests(){
    return((dispatch) => {
        firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).collection("scores").orderBy("testScore", "desc").get().then((snapshot) => {
            let completedTests = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                const data = doc.data();
                const id = doc.id;
                return { id, ...data }
            })
            dispatch({ type: USER_TESTS_COMPLETED_STATE_CHANGE, completedTests})
        })
    })
}
```

`redux/constants/index.js`:

```
export const USER_STATE_CHANGE = 'USER_STATE_CHANGE'
export const USER_TESTS_COMPLETED_STATE_CHANGE = 'USER_TESTS_COMPLETED_STATE_CHANGE'
export const CLEAR_DATA = 'CLEAR_DATA'
```

`redux/reducers/index.js`:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { user } from './user'

const Reducers = combineReducers({
    userState: user
})

export default Reducers
```

`redux/reducers/user.js`:

```
import { USER_STATE_CHANGE, CLEAR_DATA, USER_TESTS_COMPLETED_STATE_CHANGE } from "../constants"

const initialState = {
    currentUser: null,
    completedTests: [], 
}

export const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                currentUser: action.currentUser
            }
        case CLEAR_DATA:
            return initialState
        case USER_TESTS_COMPLETED_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                completedTests: action.completedTests
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

For logged-in users, the app starts in this partially-recreated `Main.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { fetchUser, clearData, fetchUserCompletedTests } from '../redux/actions/index'

export class Main extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.clearData();
        this.props.fetchUser();
        this.props.fetchUserCompletedTests();
    }
    render() {
        // bottom tab navigation buttons - between Home.js, Study.js, and Profile.js
    }
}
 
const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
    currentUser: store.userState.currentUser
})
const mapDispatchProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({fetchUser, clearData, fetchUserCompletedTests}, dispatch)
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchProps)(Main);
```

If it helps you, my `Profile.js` file has this code to sign out the user:

```
function Profile(props) {

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
    import { fetchUser } from '../../redux/actions/index'

    ...

    const onLogout = () => {
            firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
    
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }

    ...
}

    const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
        currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
    })
    const mapDispatchProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({fetchUser}, dispatch)
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchProps)(Profile);
```

**The problem started when I implemented this code into `Home.js`:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { fetchUser, fetchUserCompletedTests } from '../../redux/actions/index'

function Home(props) {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchUser();
    }, [props.currentUser] )
    
    useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchUserCompletedTests();
    }, [props.completedTests] )
    
    const { currentUser } = props;

    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <Text>Welcome back, {currentUser.name}!</Text>
                 // FlatList that shows the data stored from calling fetchUserCompletedTests()
        </View>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
    currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
    completedTests: store.userState.completedTests
})
const mapDispatchProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({fetchUser, fetchUserCompletedTests}, dispatch)
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchProps)(Home);
```

(I used `fetchUser()` and `fetchUserCompletedTests()` again in `Home.js` in order to reflect any local changes in the app whenever the user navigates to home - such as the user taking a test and then the data pertaining to that test is stored in Firebase)
**The problem occurs when I try to log out, which returns this error:**

> null is not an object (evaluating'_firebase.default.auth().currentUser.uid')

If I reload the app after receiving the error, I am then logged out. **This error did not appear prior to me using `useEffect` in `Home.js` to grab all the data everytime the user navigates to it. What am I doing wrong in my setup that causes this error when I try to log out?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at your code you only dereference uid once, here: `firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get().then((snapshot) => {`

So I would imagine this line where you're dereferencing firebase.auth() is probably where you're getting a null at.

I mean, after you call firebase.auth().signOut(), do you expect props.currentUser to change? Also if fetchUser would trigger after logout, then what do you expect firebase.auth().currentUser.uid to actually be if not null?

Is your goal to *NOT* call fetchUser after logout? If so, then maybe your props.currentUser should have an if() block around it to make sure it doesn't call fetchUser() if props.currentUser is null, for example.

If you can sort that sequence of events out, I think you'll be set.

Comment: Hey so that got me thinking about why I put it as null in the first place so I made this change in `redux/reducers/user.js`:

`const initialState = {
      currentUser: '',
      completedTests: []
}`

So far I can't find anything wrong with making this change and it seems to work completely fine.

Comment: Might be a workaround rather than a fix. Is currentUser normally a string when it's not null? If it's an object you're better off just handling it as null just from a consistency perspective. But as you found out making it non null or safely testing it's nullability are two sides of the same coin!

Comment: `currentUser` is a pretty big Firebase object that is just the relevant data of everything about the user, like uid, time of signup, email address, etc. `currentUser.uid` would be a string, though. I agree that from a consistency perspective it would make more sense to make an object `null` instead of an empty string, but this is working so I can't really complain about it. Maybe I just don't fully understand Redux yet. Who knows.

Comment: I'm happy you found a solution and thank you for the kudos and accept! I would say in closing that it's not really a function of redux. Redux is just a large object store that you put things into and there's some guard rails around it to keep the store sane. The real question is object consistency. For example how do you treat an object when it's empty/null. If it's supposed to be an object then you wouldn't normally check if it's empty by having it be an empty string. Feel free to research around for multiple opinions on these ideas!